# How to disable TinyMce's Paste plugin from turning image URLs into embedded <img>?

Tags: tinymce, plugin-tinymce

TinyMCE's Paste plugin automatically turns pasted image URLs into embedded images. https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/paste/

I need to disable this behavior since I use TinyMCE in a forum on the frontend and I don't want to allow image embedding.

Comment: It works only on image URLs ending with `.gif`, `.jpg`, `.jpeg` or `.png` (like [this image](https://cdn4.buysellads.net/uu/1/3386/1525189943-38523.png)) and it is one of the "smart paste" features in TinyMCE, and you can disable it (the feature) by setting `smart_paste` to false like [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LvmKxN). However, you should know that disabling it will also disable (as of now, two) other "smart paste" features.

Comment: @SallyCJ Thank you, it works! Once again you save me when I couldn't find a solution anywhere! How do you know all this stuff? Not even in the TinyMCE community I got an answer to this!

Comment: Check my answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> automatically turns pasted image URLs into embedded images

Yes, but only for URLs ending with `.gif`, `.jpg`, `.jpeg` and `.png`.

And that conversion is one of the "smart paste" features in TinyMCE — another one is when you select a text and paste an absolute URL (that begins with `http` or `https`), the text is automatically converted to a hyperlink (clickable link).

The relevant code is below which you can find in `wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/paste/plugin.js` which ships with WordPress — and as of writing, WordPress is still using TinyMCE version 4.9.2.

```js
var insertContent = function (editor, html) {
  if (Settings.isSmartPasteEnabled(editor) === false) {
    pasteHtml(editor, html);
  } else {
    smartInsertContent(editor, html);
  }
};
```

And if you look at the code, the smart paste features are being applied only if the `isSmartPasteEnabled` function returns `true`. The function code:

```js
var isSmartPasteEnabled = function (editor) {
  return editor.getParam('smart_paste', true);
};
```

So that function basically simply checks whether the editor configuration has the `smart_paste` option enabled — and it is **by default enabled**.

Therefore, if you'd like to disable the smart paste features, just set the `smart_paste` option to `false`. See example below and try a demo [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LvmKxN):

```js
tinymce.init({
  smart_paste: false,
  selector: 'textarea',
  plugins: 'paste'
 });
```

### Disable the smart paste features via `wp_editor()`

It's very easy. Just set `smart_paste` to `false` in the `tinymce` array:

```php
$content = '<p>Paste an image URL:</p>';
wp_editor( $content, 'editor-id', array(
    'tinymce' => array(
        'smart_paste' => false,
    ),
) );
```

### But remember this..

Setting the `smart_paste` option to `false` will disable ***all*** smart paste features. If you want to disable just the image URL-to-`img`-tag conversion, then I think you'd have to copy the Paste plugin and edit where necessary.

Comment: Thank you, it works! Do you by any chance remember what the 3rd smart_paste feature is?

Comment: I haven't dug deeper into that, but if I'm not mistaken, it removes `<meta>` tags from the pasted HTML.

Comment: Thank you, you helped me greatly with this.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. :)

Comment: PS: Actually, it seems that the meta tags removal are applied both with the smart paste features enabled and disabled. So I think there are just two smart features - the automatic `img` and `a` tags.